# powershell - removes lines based on error message

Tags: powershell, import-csv

What i'm trying to do here is give and remove local administrative permissions based on csv input (computer,user). Since our users computers tend to be offline quite a lot and a bunch of different timezones come into play, I want the script to retry to give the permissions, which it does.

The catch is, that if 1 permissions has been added/removed by the script, but another one was not at this point (due to the computer being not reachable, access denied or similar), the script will send back "Could not send Information retrying in 1 hours..." although it could successfully remove/add it for one or more of the listed entries.

So what I would like to do is once [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) returns the error message 0 (successful), I would like to remove the currently worked on csv-line from the CSV, so the CSV actually 'works off' the computers that should be done.

Could anyone help me with this? I haven't been able to find something that resembles this issue so far.

```
$Stoploop = $false
[int]$Retrycount = "0"

do {
try {
        Import-Csv "E:\Folder\Script\Remove-Admin-1.csv" | foreach {
        $DomainName = "domain.local"
        $ComputerName = $($_.Computer)
        $UserName = $($_.User)
        $AdminGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://$ComputerName/Administrators,group"
        $User = [ADSI]"WinNT://$DomainName/$UserName,user"
        $AdminGroup.Add($User.Path)
        }
    Write-Host "Job completed"
    $Stoploop = $true
    }
catch {
    if ($Retrycount -gt 24){
       Write-Host "Could not send Information after 24 retrys."
        $Stoploop = $true
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Could not send Information retrying in 1 hours..."
        Write-Host $(Get-Date)
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 3600
        $Retrycount = $Retrycount + 1
    }
}
}
While ($Stoploop -eq $false)
```

Answer (score 0):

so in order to do this you are going to need to keep an object that includes all of your failed attempts and then use that object to overwrite the existing file.  This also means that your try/catch needs to be inside of your foreach so that each computer can be treated independently.

```
$Stoploop = $false
[int]$Retrycount = "0"
$fails = @()

do {

Import-Csv "E:\Folder\Script\Remove-Admin-1.csv" | foreach {
    Try{
        $DomainName = "domain.local"
        $ComputerName = $($_.Computer)
        $UserName = $($_.User)
        $AdminGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://$ComputerName/Administrators,group"
        $User = [ADSI]"WinNT://$DomainName/$UserName,user"
        $AdminGroup.Add($User.Path)
    } catch {
        $fails += $_
        if ($Retrycount -gt 24){
            Write-Host "Could not send Information after 24 retrys."
            $fails | export-csv "E:\Folder\Script\Remove-Admin-1.csv" -NoTypeInformation
            $Stoploop = $true
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "Could not send Information retrying in 1 hours..."
            Write-Host $(Get-Date)
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 3600
            $Retrycount = $Retrycount + 1
            $fails += $_
        }
    }
}
if($fails = 0){
    Write-Host "Job completed"
    $Stoploop = $true
} elseif ($Retrycount -gt 24){
    Write-Host "Could not send Information after 24 retrys."
    $fails | export-csv "E:\Folder\Script\Remove-Admin-1.csv" -NoTypeInformation -force
    $Stoploop = $true
} else {
    Write-Host "Could not send Information retrying in 1 hours..."
    Write-Host $(Get-Date)
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 3600
    $Retrycount = $Retrycount + 1
    $fails | export-csv "E:\Folder\Script\Remove-Admin-1.csv" -NoTypeInformation -force
}


}
While ($Stoploop -eq $false)
```

Comment: Hi Mike,
thank you for your quick reply, sadly it didn't quite get it to work.
In order to fill the csv correctly added -header Computer,User and removed that line from the CSV.
The issue i'm still facing that it does not fill the CSV. It overrides the csv but does not put content in it.
Do you have any suggestion on how to solve this?
Thank you!